# php str_replace dollar sign

Tags: php, replace, str-replace

Hi I am having trouble replacing a string with dollar sign

```
$string = "The $NAME brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
echo preg_replace('/\$NAME/', "Sample Name", $string);
```

Output:

```
The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
```

The problem is that $NAME is not replaced with Sample Name.
I will be happy if there will be any help to solve my problem.

Comment: Since you aren't doing any regular expression search and replace, I suggest using str_replace instead.

Answer (score 4):

That's because PHP has [helpfully replaced the text in the string with the contents of `$NAME`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) for you. Tell it to not do that.

```
$string = 'The $NAME brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';
```

Comment: Specifically... use of double quotes allows for string interpolation, where variable names are parsed and replaced with their string values.  Single quotes do not allow for string interpolation, leaving the literal value of `$NAME` in there.

Comment: I would change the `$NAME` to something like `{NAME}` as well. Means you can't accidentally assign a variable to it

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$string = 'The $NAME brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';
echo str_replace('$NAME', "Sample Name", $string);
```

The solution to put the string in single quotes rather than in double-quotes (") since PHP will try to interpret for special characters.

Comment: ...this will not work. It tries to use $ as its delimiter and throws a warning.

Comment: Sorry...Its a type I meant str_replace !

Comment: Please explain your code. Answers that only contain code do not explain anything, which is what StackOverflow is all about.